# Using parameters in unit tests in Python 3.x from IDEA

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing

We run unit tests in Python that have previously been hard coded with information such as which server we want tests to run on. Instead, I'd like to pass that information to the test via command line argument. The problem is that using the Python unit testing framework, I'm stuck calling my custom parameters as a single parameter which is then caught by utrunner.py which assumes that the parameter is about which tests to run (regarding test discovery).

So running from IDEA I send out this command to start up the test suite:

```
C:\Users\glenp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe C:\Users\glenp\.IntelliJIdea2016.3\config\plugins\python\helpers\pycharm\utrunner.py C:\Root\svn\trunk\src\test\python\test.py "server=deathStar language=klingon"  true
```

This is the parameters that get read back to me from `print(sys.argv)`:

```
['C:\\Users\\glenp\\.IntelliJIdea2016.3\\config\\plugins\\python\\helpers\\pycharm\\utrunner.py', 'C:\\Root\\svn\\trunk\\src\\test\\python\\schedulePollTest.py', 'server=deathStar language=klingon', 'true']
```

Note, I'm not actually calling my own test, I'm calling the utrunner.py with my test as one of the arguments to it.

I get a FileNotFound error: `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'server=deathStar language=klingon'` which kills the test before I get to run it.

I think I need to modify either this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
  unittest.main()
```

or this:

```
class testThatWontRun(unittest.TestCase):
```

I COULD modify imp.py, which is throwing the error, but I happen to be on a team and modifying core Python functionality isn't going to scale well at all. (And everyone on the team will be sad)

So, is there a way to phrase my arguments in a way that utrunner.py (and imp.py) will ignore those parameters?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way to get the utrunner.py to ignore the parameters: put a -- in front of the parameter you want it to ignore.

so server=deathStar becomes --server=deathStar

Thank you rubber ducky :)